# Symfony Doctrine Form creation error

Tags: symfony-1.4

I created the Form.i click the new link button display only title,did not work include_partial(),

What is the problem? any body plz help me.other module forms works fine.
This is newsuccess.php(template)

```
            <h1>New Album</h1>


                   <?php include_partial('form', array('editFormFields'=>$editFormFields)) ?>
```

this is my form.php

```
           <?php use_stylesheets_for_form($form) ?> 
           <?php use_javascripts_for_form($form) ?>


       <form action="<?php echo url_for('album/'.    ($form->getObject()->isNew() ? 

      'create' : 'update').(!$form->getObject()->isNew() ? '?id='.$form->getObject

           ()->getId() : '')) ?>" method="post" <?php $form->isMultipart() and print 

        'enctype="multipart/form-data" ' ?>>
            <?php if (!$form->getObject()->isNew()): 

            ?>
             <input type="hidden" name="sf_method" value="put" />
           <?php endif; ?>
                    <table>


                 <tfoot>
                     <tr>
                    <td colspan="2">
                   &nbsp;<a href="<?php 

               echo url_for('album/index') ?>">Back to list</a>
                    <?php if (!$form-

                    >getObject()->isNew()): ?>
                       &nbsp;<?php echo link_to('Delete', 

        'album/delete?id='.$form->getObject()->getId(), array('method' => 'delete', 

        'confirm' => 'Are you sure?')) ?>
               <?php endif; ?>
                    <input 

                  type="submit" value="Save" />
               </td>
                     </tr>
                    </tfoot>
                   <tbody>


                     <?php echo $form ?>
                   </tbody>
                   </table>
                      </form>
```

My apachy error log nothing to display

Plz help me.

Answer (score 1):

name of partials should begin with _, so it should be

> `_form.php`

"The partial file name is _mypartial.php and is looked for in modules/mymodule/templates/" from http://www.symfony-project.org/api/1_4/PartialHelper#method_include_partial

Comment: Hi prasad,Thanks for ur reply.solved that problem.but i have another ona error.i changed some fields. i have the following error.Notice: Undefined variable: planbook in -form.php line 37 that line is  <?php echo $planbook->getTitleName() ?> and call to a memeber function getTitleName() error. plz help me.

Comment: I have answered that question as well. Pl accept the answer & upvote if it solves the problem.

Comment: hi,i saw ur answer,and changed .but still same problem.plz paste full line.plz